# How can be combined the CPM readings from two Geiger counters?

Tags: measurements, particle-detectors

I have two identical Geiger counters, they are very close each other, they are turned on at the same time and turned off after one day.

The display of the first one shows $N_1$ CPM, the second one shows $N_2$ CPM.

What is the "true" $N$ CPM value?

My first idea is to take the average, so $N=\frac{N_1+N_2}{2}$ but I feel it is wrong; my second idea is that I will not be able to know a point estimate for $N$ but I will need to seek for a statistical distribution for $N$.

I have read about the *dead time* of a Geiger counter and so I think about this extreme case: let's assume that every time the first counter detect an event the second one is in the dead time period, in this extreme case I would say that $N=N_1+N_2$, isn't it?

But I think that the probability of the above assumption is very low and so $N_U=N_1+N_2$ is an upper bound; but what is a lower bound $N_L$? I would say $N_L=\max(N_1,N_2)$ but I am not able to explain it.

Finally, I am afraid the answer is quite complicate, may you give me some pedagogical paper about it?

**Edit:**

Answers to this comment: [How can be combined the CPM readings from two Geiger counters?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/773209/how-can-be-combined-the-cpm-readings-from-two-geiger-counters?noredirect=1#comment1736370_773209)

1. Radioactive source is the background radiation.
2. The geometry is similar to this<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

3. The count rate is about 20CPM (one single tube working).
4. The two tubes are СБМ-20, the dead time is about 200µs.

<sup>1</sup>Picture is from https://www.tindie.com/products/gglabs/grad-dual-geiger-tube-arduino-radiation-sensor/#

Comment: What is your radioactive source? Can you include a sketch of your experiment's geometry? Is your count rate more like one count per minute, or one per second, or one per millisecond? Does the manual for your detector (which you can probably find online if you know its manufacturer and model number) include an estimate of the dead time?

Comment: @rob please see my update. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses [version 2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/773209/2) of the question, which gives some details about the experiment.

Background radiation, unless you take special precautions, is overwhelmingly from cosmic ray muons.  The momentum distribution of cosmic muons is strongly peaked in the "down" direction, since they are produced in the atmosphere, which also acts as a (weak) absorber, and because the muon lifetime is finite.  The cosmic rays don't *only* come from *straight* up, which is why the Ice Cube detector in Antarctica observes the northern celestial hemisphere.  But most cosmic rays are mostly vertical..

A more useful quantity than "counts per minute" is "counts per minute per unit area."
Since the distance between your detectors is comparable to their size, the effective area of your two-element detector for cosmic rays will depend on its orientation. If the parallel tubes are next to each other on a table, a vertical muon will pass through at most one tube, and you should expect the individual events in one tube to be independent of the events in the other tube.  For that case, the effective area of two tubes is twice the effective area of a single tube.  However, if one of the tubes is vertically above the other, then vertical cosmic rays have a good chance of passing through both tubes.  You would also expect a rate decrease, due to the decrease in effective area, if you oriented the tubes vertically.

A common advanced-lab experiment is to align two detectors vertically and build a "coincidence trigger," which tells you when both detectors have fired at the same time.  That lets you distinguish vertically-traveling radiation versus radiation from other directions.  You can use this to measure the angular distribution of cosmic rays yourself.  Accurately computing the angular acceptance and effective area of two tubes in coincidence is the kind of problem that makes a physics grad student spend the evening remembering their favorite swear words; if you don't need the details, you can just choose to have an un-normalized rate per unit area.

If you are seeing an event every three seconds (20 counts per minute), and you have a dead time of 200µs, your dead time fraction is
$
\frac{200\ \rm\mu s}{3\rm\ s} \approx 10^{-4}
$.
With such a large live fraction, missed events due to pile-up will be a much smaller effect than your uncertainty in the effect area of the tube.  I wouldn't worry about it in the slightest.

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly:

If you want counts per minute, add the number of counts and divide by the estimated live time.

If you want counts per minute per counter, divide counts per minute by the number of counters.

If you want counts per minute per gram of medium (sensible for gamma rays), divide counts per minute by the number of grams of gas in your geiger tube(s).

If you want counts per minute per square cm (alphas and betas), divide counts per minute by the total entrance window area of your geiger tubes.

And then, if that's not good enough, the rabbit hole here is very deep...

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your setup. I will assume that the two measurements are independent. If this is not the case, the calculation becomes severely more complicated.

The counts $X$ of a single measurement device follow a Poissonian distribution, $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$. The Poissonian distribution is characterised by a single parameter $\lambda$, which is often call *rate*. The rate is equal to the average count value $\lambda=E[X]$ as well as to the variance of the counts $\lambda=Var[X]$. Therefore, for a single device we are able to state the average rate and its uncertainty (=standard deviation of the counts).

Your question addresses the challenge of combining the results of two devices. One proper method to combine two measurement results $\{X_1, X_2\}$ is by using Bayesian statistics. The average value is given by the weighted average
$$
E[X_{12}] = \sum_{i=1}^2 w_i X_i
$$
using the inverse variance as weights,
$w_i =  \frac{\frac{1}{Var[X_i]}}{\frac{1}{Var[X_1]} + \frac{1}{Var[X_2]}} $. Note that the denominator in $w_i$ is just a normalisation constant. The standard deviation of this normalisation constant yields
the uncertainty of the average value
$$
Sd[X_{12}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \frac{1}{Var[X_1]} + \frac{1}{Var[X_2]} }}
$$